# How to dynamically load extra data for LeafletJS Popup on load

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I am upgrading a JSF page I have that shows data on a map with OSM basemap and the latest stable leaflet release for markers and functionality.

For each marker I have some basic information for the element which is loaded when the marker is created. However there is some data that needs to be displayed for available days that I do not want to load before the user actually clicks the popup, since I expect it to create a much bigger load than what is necessary.

Is there a way to use a promise to first load the extra data required and then open the popup once a user clicks it?

Comment: In your title you say on load. In your text you say clicks the popup and then you speak of a promise. Which behaviour do you want ?

Comment: The data has to be loaded once the user clicks it, so it's on click and it has to keep the popup from opening until the data is received. Right now, the request is indeed made on marker click, but the popup loads anyway and the data received is wasted.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. However, something has to happen when the user clicks (an hourglass or something) to show this is a length operation. Is there a way to show what you have now ?

Comment: I wouldn't mind a waiting/loading gif icon to be displayed, I think it'll look better that way too. And loading only the required data (name,lat,lon) for each marker would definitely be a lot faster for the end user to mind a second or two(at worst) of wait. Right now I scrapped my code to be ready for Monday, but if anyone has an idea or example to point me....

Comment: Thank you very much FranceImage! I just tested an idea I was inspired by your comment, and once it works I'll post it here! I just load a dummy popup first, then on the click methods I just wait for the data to come, bind the new popup to the marker, close the old popup and it's ready!

Comment: I'm glad you are progressing. I was wondering: why do you need to get some data on each click ? Is it an option to load all of it in the first place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem was embarassingly easy...

You start at marker creation by doing:

```
function onMapClick(e){

    dataPromise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ /*grab your data here*/ });        

    dataPromise.then(function(result){
       popupPromise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
          e.target.closePopup();
          e.target.unbindPopup();
          newPopup = createPopupFromServerData(result);
          resolve(newPopup);
        });
   });

   popupPromise .then(function(result){
         e.target.bindPopup(result).openPopup();
   });
}


    marker.bindPopup("Loading element data, please wait..."); //this can include anything
    marker.on('click', onMapClick);
```

It was the second promise that was needed to properly open a new Popup, and it escaped me for two days.

Comment: Were you actually trying to load markers first and then the data for each marker popup?

Comment: because, i wanna do that and if this is what the solution is then i would be grateful to you, btw is "result" a JSON object?